# MultiBinding vs ViewModel properties for Commands inside bound WPF MVVM ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following scenario in my WPF MVVM application. There is a ListView which binds to a collection (`Orders`) on the ViewModel. For each object in the collection, a row of data about that item is displayed.

There is also a cell which is itself bound to another ViewModel collection (`SelectedDates`) which creates a checkbox for each item in the SelectedDates collection.

When a user clicks the checkbox, a command needs to be activated. The parameters for that command have to be the ID of the corresponding Order and SelectedDate object.

Now, I know I can use a MultiBinding and a converter to achieve this. What interested me was that, when researching this, it seemed generally agreed that it would be better to have one or both parameters as ViewModel properties and avoid passing them as parameters altogether.

However, I am at a loss to see how, in this particular scenario (or, indeed, many scenarios where you're dealing with a command generated inside a ListView bound to a ViewModel collection) one could achieve this.

So the question is - is it possible to do this entirely or partially using ViewModel properties, or in this instance is the MultiBinding the only way to get the job done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about MVVM is that generally, we have the data in the view model, so we don't need to access the UI controls. Therefore, if you data bound an `Order` property to the `ListView.SelectedItem` property, then that property will reflect the selected item... that is how you could get the `Order.Id` value from the data bound `Order` object:

```
int id = SelectedOrder.Id;
```

Now with the `SelectedDates` collection, I'm assuming that you also have access to that, either directly from the view model, or indirectly through the selected `Order` object. Presumably, your `Order` class has some kind of `DateTime` property that is data bound to the selected date from the collection. If that is so, then you could attach an `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` handler to the `Order` item in the view model which would get called each time the value changes:

In `Order` class:

```
public DateTime SomeProperty
{
    get { return someProperty; }
    set
    {
        someProperty = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
    }
}
```

In view model:

```
public Order SelectedOrder
{
    get { return selectedOrder; }
    set
    {
        selectedOrder = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedOrder");
        selectedOrder.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

...

```
private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SomeProperty")
    {
        // Do something here with SelectedOrder and SelectedOrder.SomeProperty here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you're wanting to fire a command on an item in a collection that will result in a different collection being updated.

One way to achieve this would be to create a viewmodel class for your `Order` (someone needs to come up with a better, less confusing term for this kind of viewmodel compared to the kind of ViewModel that acts as the DataContext for a view ...) which has the `IsSelected` property you need to act as the binding target for the `CheckBox` within the `ListView` items. Your main VM then maintains a collection of `OrderVm` rather than `Order` directly. You could then define the getter for your `SelectedDates` collection as something like:

`OrderVm.Where(x=>x.IsSelected)`

... and forgo the setter, because it is really just a reflection of the properties of something else.